# Set ListView Adapter with composite PRIMARY KEY in SQLite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've bound data from a SQLite database table to a ListView using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. This works well when I use `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` as my table's primary key. However, I'm trying to use a composite primary key such as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
column1,
column2,
column3,
PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2));
```

From what I can gather, the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor requires the _id column to work. I cannot find a way to construct the `SimpleCursorAdapter` with the composite primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just collate them in your raw query as `_ID`

```
select column1 || '_' || column2 as _ID, column1, column2,column3 from table
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I ended up doing something different. I used INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, without the autoincrement, and had my algorithm construct an _id to pass to the row creation function.